# mongoDB friend relationships

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm building a web app that functions like a social map site where users can see where their friends checked in. Users should only see their immediate friends, and people who have joined the same group. I'm trying to get my head around doing this in a noSQL database like mongoDB.

In an SQL database I would have a table 3 tables.

1) users, their check ins

2) user pairs (friends)

3) user pairs with groups

To return the right data it would be a relatively simple matter of a join query.

In mongoDB I imagine I would have 2 collections.

1) users. In each user would be a sub document of check ins, a sub document of friends and a sub document of groups joined.

2) Groups. Each document would contain a subdocument of users in that group.

I'd compile a list of users from both collections and then query their check ins from the first collection.

This seems quite cumbersome and I haven't spend much time with noSQL so I want to learn how to use it but I think this is a poor application of it. Will this work fine? Or should I be looking at a different type of database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add check ins (places?) as its own collection. You can then do a join using aggregation pipelines and [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#use-lookup-with-an-array)